# What does refreshing a Dataflow in the PBI service actually do?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In the PBI service, there is a refresh option for dataflows. What does a refresh operation for dataflows actually do?

Answer (score 2):

A Power BI **Dataflow** is much like a data storage component on its own (internally using Azure Data Lake) and and a refresh will simply update data from the connected data source by applying all the predefined ETL steps.

The biggest advantage of **Dataflows** is that a Power BI **Dataset** can connect to more than one of them at a time so that you can define your ETL steps in one place only and feed the results into serveral datasets, avoiding code duplication.

Another advantage is probably that you can author your ETL code directly in the Online Service w/o a PBIDesktop.exe

When refreshing **Datasets** be aware that they do not trigger a refresh of the connected **Dataflows**. This has to be scheduled separately.

Comment: Thanks Peter - Great answer. I am using DirectQuery against a dataflow. Therefore, based on your answer, I will need to refresh my dataflows or I could potentially get stale data. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflows are essentially the cloud version of M queries in Power Query / Query Editor. A Dataflow is the ETL layer that connects to the data sources, extracts and transforms the data, then stores the result as a table.

When you refresh a Datafow, it's just like refreshing a query in a Power BI model. It re-connects to the underlying data sources and pulls in the data from those sources as they exist at the time of refresh and stores the transformed data which can then be used in data models.

Things are a bit more complex with DirectQueries, linked tables, and incremental refreshes, which I'm choosing to ignore for the sake of simplicity.

---

Resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-introduction-self-service

https://radacad.com/dataflow-vs-dataset-what-are-the-differences-of-these-two-power-bi-components